# What should the Header of a Created Response contain, if there is no Endpoint to acces the created Resource

Tags: rest, http

If i have a post endpoint for a car, but only get endpoints for a collection of cars, what should be the created URL in the Response. Usually it should be cars/{id-of-new-car}
But since that endpoint does not exists, that URL is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a collection, and you used `POST` on that collection to add a new car, you didn't *create* any new resources, you just updated one (the collection).

So if your question is: What should go in the `Location` header that goes along with the `201 Created` response, I'd say you probably don't need either.